# I can see a bear go over the river

Tags: complementation, bare-infinitives, verbs-of-perception

> A bear **goes** over the river.
>
> I can see a bear **go** over the river.

Are the sentences above correct?
If the sentence has "can", *goes* will become *to go*?

[image]

Comment: It doesn't depend on *can*, it depends on *see*.

Comment: Can explain why "see" make the changes? and what other word will change goes to go?

Comment: **Over** sound odd to me as to a non-native speaker. Should not it be **across**?

Comment: That sentence is get from Hainemann story book.

Comment: @SovereignSun **over** suggests that the bear crosses the river without touching the water, as you can see in the illustration. **Across** would suggest that the bear traversed the river by swimming.

Comment: Oh, so it has a slight shade in meaning.

Comment: @DamkerngT.  Thank you. The explanation is much more clearer.

Comment: @SovereignSun the tree log lies *over* the river, the bear walks/goes *over* the river, (without getting wet) *across* could imply that the bear was *in* the river and  walked from one side of the river to the other.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I got it already. I was finding a similar meaning in the sentence "to go over a street" but there's no such thing, you "go across the street".

Comment: Verbs of perception (see, hear, watch, feel, etc) use this pattern:  {perception verb} {noun-phrase} {bare infinitive|present participle}.  *She heard the rain strike|striking the tin roof.*  *He watched the weasel slink|slinking through the underbrush.* See Araucaria's answer at the link provided above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Glorfindel noted, this is due to *see*, not because of *can*. This is a common construction in English. Other verbs that have the same effect include *observe*, *watch*, *hear*, *feel*.

There's a good explanation here: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/hear-see-etc-object-infinitive-or-ing

Comment: How about citing something  from the webpage? Links can change, rot or become broken over time...